# How to scrape this type of paragraph

Tags: python

I am trying to scrape a website but I don't know what to specify for paragraphs.

What should i put ?

The paragraphs are coded like this :

[image]

This is what I get :

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import simpledialog
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import os

def scrape_url(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    paragraphs = soup.find_all('p')
    
    download_path = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'Downloads', 'paragraphs.csv')
    
    with open(download_path, 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        writer.writerow(['Texte du Paragraphe'])
        for paragraph in paragraphs:
            writer.writerow([paragraph.get_text()])
            
    print(f"Les paragraphes ont été écrits avec succès dans '{download_path}'.")

def ask_url():
    ROOT = tk.Tk()
    ROOT.withdraw()
    USER_INP = simpledialog.askstring(title="Scraper Web", prompt="Entrez l'URL du site à scraper:")
    return USER_INP

url = ask_url()

if url:
    scrape_url(url)
else:
    print("Aucune URL fournie.")
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is looking for paragraphs, but it should be looking for `spans` inside of paragraphs based on the HTML you posted.

You should use [css selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.php) to locate the `spans` with class `se-fs` inside paragraphs of class `se-text-paragraph`.

The select code would be

```py
paragraphs = soup.select('p.se-text-paragraph > span.se-fs-')
```

Comment: Thank you ! Why soup instead of beautifulsoup ?

Comment: `soup` is the instance of `BeautifulSoup` you created when you called `soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')` in your code. I highly recommend following the Quick Start guide for Beautiful Soup on this website before continuing with your project: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#quick-start

Comment: Sadly it doesn't write anything :/